# Storing a large, sparse array for R and Python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, data-management, data-storage, r

I've been working in R but sometimes switching to python. I'd like a more inter-language portable way of storing a large array than a csv file. (The particular csv file I'm dealing with is about 10^6 rows by 10^3 columns, but only about 1% of the entries are non-zero.) Processing a large csv file everytime I start up R or Python takes far too long.

I've heard HDF5 is a great solution for this, but I have limited experience with it. Is HDF5 appropriate for storing non-hierarchical array data? What about for a single sparse array? I also am unsure which HDF5 R package to use.

Comment: Just a side note: for python there is sparse matrix support in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html For R you can check http://stackoverflow.com/q/1167448/1499402 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10717741/1499402

Comment: Another side note: h5py (http://code.google.com/p/h5py/) is a very easy to use HDF5 library for Python.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in a "standardized" format, you should have a look at the [matrix market exchange formats](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html). The "coordinate format" (which is good for sparse matrices) simply adds metadata to the format suggested by Aron in his [answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/3058/1744) and specifies how the data has to be formatted.

Comment: Indeed. In Python you can even use `scipy.io.mmwrite` and `scipy.io.mmread` to handle this for you. I suspect that R has similar library functions.

Comment: @MRocklin The R Matrix package has functions for reading and writing matrix market format (readMM and writeMM).

Comment: Where can I find more information about the coordinate format?

Comment: @user1170330 simply on the matrix market page cited above http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html#coord

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your sparse array is 2-dimensional, you can decompose it into three vectors of column (index), row (index), and value fairly easily with a single traversal of the matrix.  You can then store these vectors in whatever file format you want, no need to switch to HDF5 for that reason alone.

Comment: And if you want to look for how this array is usually described, search the web for "compressed sparse row (CSR)". For example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR_or_CRS.29

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth the format described by Aron is "coordinate list": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Coordinate_list_.28COO.29

Answer (score 2):

I happened to have this little Python function kicking around:

```
def storeSparseProblem(sp_mat, rhs, filename):
    # Convert the sparse matrix to lil
    sp_mat = sp_mat.tocoo()

    # Make a record array out of the above
    rcv = recarray((3, len(sp_mat.row)), dtype=[("row","<i8"), ("col","<i8"), ("val","<f8")])

    # Set the values
    rcv["row"] = sp_mat.row
    rcv["col"] = sp_mat.col
    rcv["val"] = sp_mat.data

    # Open the output h5
    h5 = openFile(filename, "w")

    # Save the matrix
    h5.createTable("/", "M", rcv, title="The Matrix")

    # Add the rhs
    ary = h5.createArray("/", "rhs", rhs, title="the right hand side")

    # Close it out
    h5.close()
```

You could make this faster by turning on tables's magic [blosc](http://blosc.pytables.org/trac) compression, and switching from a table to a carray, but this should at least get you started.  The load function is really simple, but I can't seem to locate it.  If someone has interest, I will code it up and post it.